# SSH Between Docker Instances between Hosts

Tags: docker, ssh

I have a setup that looks like this:
[image]

Essentially, two physical machines that exist on the same local network and each machine is running the same docker image. I have exposed a range of ports on both physical machines (2000-3000). The docker image used has both SSH and OpenSSH server installed, and when run, port `22` is mapped to `2222`. What I would like to be able to do is SSH from `Docker Image Machine-01` to `Docker Image Machine-02`.

I realize that `docker attach`, etc exist, however, I do have a specific use case for my application.

I know that my ports are open as I can have `netcat` listening on one machine, and then use `nc -zv machine-02 2000` and get a response. Where I am stuck is getting the connection between the two docker images. It should be noted that I can `SSH` into the docker image locally (`machine-01` can get into its own image, but `machine-02` cannot access this)

What is the best way of proceeding with this?